# Compare multiple files & Print similarity and Difference

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

I have 61 files (files names are like cutpathid-hca.txt, cutpathid-hey.txt, cutpathid-hpl.txt, cutpathid-hpyd.txt, cutpathid-hpz.txt),  each comprises of the list like below, I want to compare them and print similarity and difference in each file with its file name.

```
00010
00020
00030
00040
00051
00052
00500
00520
00620
00630
00640
00650
00190
00680
00910
00920
00061
00071
00072
00121
00561
00564
00565
00592
01040
00230
00240
00250
00260
00270
00280
00290
00300
00310
```

OUTPUT shoud look like

Similar lines in  cutpathid-hca.txt, cutpathid-hey.txt, cutpathid-hpl.txt, cutpathid-hpyd.txt, cutpathid-hpz.txt

```
00010
00020
00030
00040
00051
00052
00500
00520
00620
00630
00640
00650
00190
00680
00910
00920
00061
00071
00072
00121
```

Unique lines in cutpathid-hca.txt

00240
00250
00260

unique lines in cutpathid-hpl.txt

00290
00300

unique lines in cutpathid-hpz.txt

00051
00052

Comment: Do you want to do a pairwise comparison between all files? What should the output look like?

Comment: Each of the 61 files has 34 lines, and you want to know which files have the same or different contents of each of those lines? Or can you clarify what "similar" and "different" mean to you?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Each of the 61 files has more than 1500 lines  and yes i want to know which files have the same or different contents of each of those lines.

Comment: do they all have the same number of lines?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes almost some files may have a difference of 5 to 10 lines.

Comment: to  Kusalananda's point, what should the report look like, particularly in the case of missing lines?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Schaller should look like    similar in  cutpathid-hca.txt, cutpathid-hey.txt, cutpathid-hpl.txt, cutpathid-hpyd.txt, cutpathid-hpz.txt 
00020
00030
00040
00051
00052
00500
00630
00910 Unique in cutpathid-hca.txt                                                               00270
00280                                                                                                             unique in cutpath-hey.txt                                                                              00300
00310

Comment: You'll have a better time [editing the desired output into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/466749/edit), as comments have limited formatting and can be deleted.

Comment: @JeffSchaller kindly look edited question.

Comment: It's confusing to use the word "similar". Would "10" and "0010" and "010" and "000010" be "similar" or "unique"? I notice the lines happen to be in increasing numerical order; can that be assumed?

Comment: They are basically identification codes in my data set each consist of 5 digits, 10" and "0010" and "010" and "000010" all are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, standard `diff` supports only two files at a time.

You can easily install [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) (it's a python program so it should work on every "recent" linux/bsd/*nix distribution) which looks like it can diff more than 2 files at a time.

**Edit as per comment**

Actually, `Diffuse` is a GUI program. I've just installed it ad made a quick test with 3 files.

Command was:

```
diffuse /tmp/file_1.txt /tmp/file_2.txt /tmp/file_3.txt
```

and results as in this screenshot:

[image: Diffuse output]